# I have a sorted, unique and duplicated values in Column A. Need to output certain value in each row, col B, except the last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

is there a way to solve this problem that I have currently? Thanks in advance!

I have a sorted email address in Column A and the duplicates are back to back. I would like to automate the number '10' in the same row of the duplicated address but -1 number of times. If i have 3 email address that are the same in that column, i would like output a fixed value in another cell of the same row for the first 2 email address and another fixed value for the 3 address.

Example:
In column A I have an email address 'a@email.com' in row 1, 2 and 3. I would like to put number '10' in column B of row 1 and 2 and '0' in row 3.

On row 4 and 5, email address 'b@email.com'. I would like to put '10' in B4 and '0' in B5.

On Row 6, email address 'c@email.com'. I would like to manually put in a number in column B since there are no duplicates of 'c@email.com' in the row.

etc...

[Screenshot of the google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNmKL.png)

Comment: As contributor idfurw has pointed out, you cannot have both a formula and manual entry responsible for the same cell(s). You must choose one or the other. However, you can apply an array formula for the rule and then use an override column that the array formula can reference for places where you want something different. The most efficient way to help you set that up would be to share a link to a copy of a spreadsheet with a small amount of realistic manual data already entered into it and the link's permission set (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot make manual input inside the output range of `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Therefore, you may consider the use of single formula:

```
=IF(A2=A3,10,IF(A2=A1,0,))
```

Which would give a blank output if no duplicate.

You could then find it out and edit.